# Showing that an operator is a topological isomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ is a complete normed space and that $T:X \rightarrow X$ is bounded and linear. If $\|T\| < 1$, then prove that $I-T$ is a topological isomorphism and find $(I-T)^{-1}$.

We can show $I-T$ is a topological isomorphism if we can show that it is surjective and that it satisfies $\alpha \|x\| \leq \|x-Tx\| \leq \beta \|x\|$ for some positive numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Easily, by assumption, we can get that $\|x-Tx\| \leq \|x\|+\|Tx\| \leq \|x\| + \|T\|\|x\| < 2\|x\|$, so we can choose $\beta=2$. However, I am having trouble coming up with a lower bound $\alpha$. Showing that the function is surjective is giving me hard time as well. As for finding a formula for the inverse, it seems like it would be the composition of $T$ with itself infinitely many times, but I am not sure if this is even well defined.

Any help is appreciated.

Krull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\|T\| < 1$ we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|T^n\| \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty\|T\|^n <\infty$$
And since $X$ is complete every absolutely convergent series converges, hence $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty T^n$ converges. Then

\begin{align} (I-T)S &= (I-T) \left(\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^k T^n\right) \\
&=\left(\lim_k \sum_{n=0}^k T^n\right)-\left(\lim_k \sum_{n=1}^{k+1}T^n\right) \\
&= \lim_k (I - T^{k+1}) \\
&= I \end{align}
A similar computation shows $S(I-T) = I$. Hence $(I-T)^{-1} = S$.

Alternatively if you know some spectral theory, then to quickly see that $I-T$ is invertible we could note that $\text{spr}(T) \le \|T\| < 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your input, this is very instructive. Do you have any hints/ideas for the other questions, such as surjectivity?

Comment: I've shown $I-T$ is invertible and any invertible operator is bounded below and surjective. In particular $I-T$ is bounded below by $\|S\|^{-1} = \left\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty T^n\right\|^{-1}$, and as for surjectivity we have that if $x \in X$ then $x = (I-T)(Sx) = (I-T)(\sum_{n=1}^\infty T^n x)$.